# Insert Query If Statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, insert

I created a process form that inserts values from one php page into the database. I would like to email the results of the form to several users using some type of authentication method. I thought I could achieve this with `mysql_query()`, but it plugs in the data, but isn't sending a email.

```
$sql = insert query
$connection = mysql_connect
```

I used:

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection))
 {
     die('Error' . mysql_error());
 }
```

I tried to insert `mail()` after the if statement, but it doesn't work. If I insert `mail()` after the die statement anyone is able to process the file and send emails. How can I get this to work? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to give more information, I think; for one thing, if you've got a `mail()` line after the `die()` line, it will never run, because processing of the code stops at `die()`. When you say `mail()` doesn't work if you add it after the if - where did you add it? What happens when you tried to run it? Was there an error message? Was the email sent? Did nothing seem to happen at all?

Comment: Are you supplying any arguments to `mail()` ?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, this is the best answer I could give on the situation.

```
$query = mysql_query($sql,$connection);
if($query === true){
    //mail code
    mail();
} else {
    //Log some errors here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you execute mysql_query function, it returns a resource id in case of success.
So you can use in this way:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,connection);

if($result){
    // mail function
    mail();
}else{
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

And as you stated, **mail** function is called after **die**(), that should be possible only in case, when no **mysql_error** is thrown and **mail** function is called out of the if loop.